# Converting shapefile to raster using ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, convert

How do I convert a shapefile to a raster image using ArcMap 10?

What functions within the conversion toolbox do I use?

Comment: The right answer, Justin, depends on (a) the dimensions of the features, (b) what the data mean, and (c) your objectives.  Points, lines, and polygons can be converted into rasters that represent the shapes only (but have no data).  Values associated with the shapes can also be *interpolated* (in many different ways) or *spread* (usually using a "kernel density" operation) into a "continuous" field of values.  So, to make this an answerable question, please indicate your situation with respect to (a), (b), and (c).

Comment: I think here for you https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PLOOeH_x1mw
it convert shapefile to raster

Answer (score 4):

I presume you have a point shapefile which you want to turn into raster.

There is an ArcMap 10 tool Point to Raster (Conversion) that should do the job.

You can set raster cell size and output raster image format, ie, .tif, .img etc.

More info can be found under the following link: 
http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00120000002z000000

Answer (score 0):

From within ArcMap you can manually save your map view to Tiff, Bmp, Pdf, etc.
File, Export Map, Save as type.

Answer (score 0):

In ArcMap, you open arctoolbox

choose feature to raster in conversion tools

toturial here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DgggjedCOoI